# In a Google Cloud Function, can you specify an alternative pip repository that doesn't require authentication?

Tags: pip, google-cloud-functions

Google clearly documents that there is no way for the Cloud Function build process to use an alternative pip repository that requires authentication. But is there any way to use one that doesn't require authentication? I don't see any way to specify an alternate repository location.

Comment: AFAIK, no, it's not possible. You can use Cloud Run if you want to customize your build and run environment. You can also directly provide the libraries in a lib directory and use them.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, there is no way yet to build an alternative pip repository that doesn’t require authentication.

Private dependencies are used.
Dependencies are installed in a Cloud Build environment where SSH keys are not available.

As explained in the last section, packages hosted in repositories that require SSH-based authentication must be vendored and uploaded alongside your project's source.
Before deploying your project, use the pip install command with the -t DIRECTORY argument to transfer private dependencies into a local directory:

Place your dependent in a local directory as follows:

```
pip install -t DIRECTORY DEPENDENCY
```

To make it into a module, place an empty init.py file in the DIRECTORY directory.
Import from this module to use your dependency:

```
import DIRECTORY.DEPENDENCY
```

[Specifying dependencies in Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python)

With the recommendation of the only comment for your question, here is a [Setting up authentication to Python Package Repository](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#keyring-setup) document, you should verify that the required [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#gcp) are configured.

Comment: After following instructions from google (that as of today still show like you've posted) I am unable import from the library as it depends on another library (which was also downloaded inside the directory I specified).  It would seem that I would need to set it in my path? Does google do that automatically?